# bootstrap CSS styling of text input placeholder

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been racking my brains out to fix this but I am not an HTML/CSS expert so I'm out of my wits.

The placeholder text is shown too high from the center of the input box element.

See the following image:

[image: placeholder too high]

How can I fix this? You can see them live at http://siliconalley.com. When you type inside the input, it actually looks alright. It's just the placeholder that is looking weird.

Comment: Have you tried Firebug / playing around with line-height?

Comment: Looking fine. Not sure what do you mean by place holder. Are you referring to vertical alignment? But that too looks fine.

Comment: @NathanLee The placeholder is the text that appears in the input tag and goes away on focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current line-height is 1, change it so it is equal to the height of your element and it becomes centered.

```
line-height: 30px;
```

Comment: Thank you. This one fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the line-height style the value of auto, with that u will fix the problem in Chrome and won't mess up in IE. I've tested on FF, Chrome and IE

```
.search-query {
    line-height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: personally i would avoid using !important, if anything always try and be more specific with your selectors, !important is just a bit "hacky" for me.. of course that's just my opinion

Comment: `auto` doesn't seem to work without !important unless I edit bootstrap.css which is something I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your `line-height:1;` declaration is causing the problem. Remove this for `.navbar-search .search-query` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

your CSS is looking Like this 
**Actually it is line-height problem**

```
.navbar-search .search-query {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 4px 14px;
font-family: Open Sans,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

**Change to Like this**

```
.navbar-search .search-query {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 4px 14px;
    font-family: Open Sans,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 21px; /**change the Line-height to like this**/
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    }
```